# Copyright in Origami

Tags: copyright

I'm trying to find any US case law addressing the issue of copyright in origami patterns. Copyright itself does not protect functionality, methods, processes, etc.; and the merger doctrine of copyright law would not allow protection of the expression of an origami pattern if there are only a limited number of patterns to create a particular resultant origami sculpture.

That being said, many origami creators claim copyright in their work and books on origami have been registered with the US Copyright Office (although the protection of such registration may only extend to the protectable elements of such book, i.e. the text, photographs, compilation of articles, etc.).

However, I cannot find a single case that addresses the issue of copyrightability of origami. Any citations or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resulting figure could surely be covered by copyright, if it is original. A new set of folds to make a known figure might not be separately protectable under US law.

In [this news story](https://keisenassociates.com/japanese-origami-artist-loses-copyright-battle-against-television-station-2/) A court in Japan is said to have held that:

> the folding instructions are indeed a copyrightable subject matter, because (i) the author’s selection of 10 out of 32 folding steps were subject to alternative modes of expression; (ii) the author’s folding instructions, including the organization of the diagrams, the texts, and the drawings, had elements of “style”; (iii) taken in its entirety, one admittedly found room for creative expression (Tokyo District Court Opinion: Case No. Heisei 23 (2011) (Wa) 18968 (Tokyo D.Ct., May 20, 2011).

But it further held that the particular diagram displayed was not an infringement of the claimed source.

In [this tech dirt podcast](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20110507/01344914197/origami-creators-sue-artist-copyright-infringement-concerning-crease-patterns.shtml) a suit over an artwork derived from a folding pattern is reported. Tech dirt thinks it is an obvious case of fair use.

The [British Origami society](https://britishorigami.info/society/useful-documents/copyright/) says:

> The issue of how the laws of copyright affect origami diagrams and models is an important one. Groups such as the Origami Artists and Creators are working towards an internationally agreed set of guidelines. Dr. Robert Lang has presented his interpretation on his website. Until a common statement is agreed, we refer people to the terms in our constitution.
>
> (1) The Society and its Members shall respect all copyrights, registered trademarks and registered designs in all models, designs, diagrams, photographs, books and writings and shall observe the laws of copyright, registered trademarks, registered designs and patents and all other provisions relating to intellectual property which are applicable in all the separate countries throughout the World.
>
> (2) This article shall apply to all models, designs, diagrams, photographs, books and writings
> whether existing in writing or print on paper or any other hard copy or existing in electronic form, photocopy or microfiche in libraries, public or private archives or on the internet or on recorded discs or tapes of any kind or in any other kind of electronic record and whether made commercially or otherwise publicly or made privately.
>
> (3) Before reproducing any model, drawing, photograph or text contained in any publication, a member of the Society shall obtain the consent of the copyright owner before publication.
>
> (4) As a matter of courtesy, whether or not required to do so by law, the Society and its Members shall give proper acknowledgement to the original author of any model, design or diagram demonstrated or reproduced in any manner.

[Origami USA](https://origamiusa.org/copyright) says that:

> OrigamiUSA is very concerned about protecting and respecting the rights of origami artists, authors, and diagrammers. While "traditional" origami models are in the public domain, the vast majority of published origami designs are of recent authorship and therefore cannot be published or used commercially without obtaining permission from their creators and/or diagrammers.

It seems that few suits on origami copyright have been filed, and then appealed to where opinions are published and thus accessible to a non-professional's search.

Comment: Siegal -- thanks so much for the very focused research. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @LawCrow  I could wish that there was a more definitive answer with an actual case on point, but I can't find one. I have a number of origami, a friend used to fold and design them very regularly.